# Where do RouteValues go if the Controller's Action doesn't have matching parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I have the following code in one of my Views:

```
@Html.Action("Grid", "Product", new { section = SectionType.Product })
```

This will call the `Grid` action method of my `ProductController`, which is all well and good. If the Grid method is defined like this:

```
public ActionResult Grid(SectionType section) { ... }
```

Then the `section` parameter will get populated with `SectionType.Product`, as I had requested. However, if I **don't** put the parameter in the method declaration, like this:

```
public ActionResult Grid() { ... }
```

Then the `section` value that was set in the View seems to completely disapper. It's not in `Request.Params`, it's not in `Request.QueryString`, and in fact I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Can anyone tell me what happens to this value? Can I retrieve it from anywhere, or does MVC completely discard it if the method does not ask for it in the parameter list?

Comment: I don't see any way to get it. I'll wait for someone more knowing, but I surmise that since you aren't actually executing a get/post that the value gets lost somewhere along the way when it has nothing to bind to. Note that if you do the same with @Html.ActionLink() you can get at it in Request.QueryString

Comment: @MikeC. yes I know about ActionLink, but I don't want the user to have to press anything - I need the page to call this Controller method by itself. I find it extremely strange that MVC isn't at least putting this value in Request.Params...

Comment: Oh I thought this was academic. Just pass the parameter as you've already shown how to do. Why are you even interested in passing without accepting the value in your controller method?

Comment: @MikeC. we need it for a specific purpose. But I don't understand what you mean to just pass the parameter as I've already shown. Passing the parameter this way without putting the parameter in the method's declaration causes it to completely disappear.

Comment: No, I mean why not just use public ActionResult Grid(SectionType section) { ... } as you have shown. But if you say you have a good reason, then I believe you. Good luck on your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access any of the parameters extracted from the route via [RouteValueDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) `Values` collection of the `RouteData` in the `RequestContext`:

```
var section = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["section"];
```

I am not sure, if it would be of the enumeration type required (i.e. `SectionType`) boxed into an `object`, or just a `string` (also boxed into an `object`) that you'll need to cast to the enumeration type appropriately yourself.

If there is no route with a segment which could obtain the value of the `section` parameter, it should be stored in the `Request.QueryString` and should be accessible through `Request.QueryString["section"]`. Also in this case the generated html should look like `...?section=SomeSection`, while in the case if you had a suitable route, it had to look like `.../SomeSection`

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to work. Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["section"] is marked as null.

Comment: @Amberite it depends also on the route, it matches. Probably the route does not have a segment named `section`...In debug mode, could you check what `Keys` and `Values` does `Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values` contain?

Comment: @Amberite actually, if it's not in the `RouteData` and (as you say in the question) it's not in the `Request.QueryString`, then you should check the generated html. Does it at all contain this `section`? is it `?section=someSection` or it's `.../SomeSection`...

Answer (score 0):

I guess `SectionType` is an enum.
If yes, then an error will be happen if no matching parameters found in Action.

```
// throw exception if you don't pass section value
public ActionResult Grid(SectionType section) { ... }
```

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'section' of non-nullable type
>   'MvcApplication1.Controllers.SectionType' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(MvcApplication1.Controllers.SectionType)' in
>   'MvcApplication1.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

From the message above, the exception is happen if no matching parameters found in the Action and the parameters is `non-nullable` type.

If you change your Action like this:

```
// nullable SectionType
public ActionResult Grid(SectionType? section) { ... }
```

or

```
// default value
public ActionResult Grid(SectionType section = SectionType.Area) { ... }
```

When `section` is `nullable` types, the Action will be called with `section` value is null.
When `section` have default value, the Action will be called with `section` value is null but in the action it will be use default value.

Comment: I think you have it backwards :) .. I am not concerned about calling the method without the parameter. I am concerned about calling the method WITH a parameter, when that method DOES NOT have that parameter in its declaration. In essence, I'm telling MVC "I am calling a method called Grid, and I'm passing along this 'section' value. The method Grid does not a 'section' parameter, but I'd still like you to store it somewhere." Does that make sense?